# How to suppress the display of column header(s) in DynamicJasper?

Tags: java, jasper-reports, dynamic-jasper

Using DynamicJasper and FastReportBuilder is it possible to suppress the display of column header(s)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**`setPrintColumnNames(false)`**](http://dynamicjasper.com/docs/current/apidocs/ar/com/fdvs/dj/domain/builders/DynamicReportBuilder.html#setPrintColumnNames(boolean))

> When FALSE, no column names are printed (in the header band)

**Example**

```
FastReportBuilder drb = new FastReportBuilder();
frb.setPrintColumnNames(false);
```

**Note:** [`FastReportBuilder`](http://dynamicjasper.com/docs/current/apidocs/ar/com/fdvs/dj/domain/builders/FastReportBuilder.html) inherited method from `DynamicReportBuilder` since it extends it.

Comment: Thanks!  That did exactly what I wanted.